# What does each field represent in <filename>.log file in $logs folder in an Azure container of an Azure storage account

Tags: azure, databricks

I want find what each column represent in .log file in $logs folder in an Azure container in an Azure Storage account . Any help is most Appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the schema of blobs in `$logs` container here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format.

This is the information provided on this page:

```
<version-number>;<request-start-time>;<operation-type>;<request-status>;
<http-status-code>;<end-to-end-latency-in-ms>;<server-latency-in-ms>;
<authentication-type>;<requester-account-name>;<owner-account-name>;
<service-type>;<request-url>;<requested-object-key>;
<request-id-header>;<operation-count>;<requester-ip-address>;
<request-version-header>;<request-header-size>;<request-packet-size>;
<response-header-size>;<response-packet-size>;<request-content-length>;
<request-md5>;<server-md5>;<etag-identifier>;<last-modified-time>;
<conditions-used>;<user-agent-header>;<referrer-header>;<client-request-id>
```